# document.write("Final i = "+i,"<br>");

Tags: javascript, for-loop, continue

Why can't I understand the process of continue?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        continue;
        document.write(i + "<br>");

    }
    document.write("Final i=" + i + "<br>");
```

The result says 11 but I think the result mignt be 10. 
Why 11? I can't understand it.

Comment: The source code you have provided has syntax errors. Please update your question can correct the source code to output the same as what you are working with.

Comment: Your `for` condition should be `i<10;` if your expected output is **10**. You can get more information about Comparison operators here: [**Comparison operators documentation**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: I updated the code! Thx!!

Comment: because only on 11 the condition of the loop doesn't match (because 10==10, so `i` increases), so the code continue with 11 and print it

Comment: because the loop must check the last value that doesn't match. It doesn't know what will be the **next** value (We know, because we're human, so we're smarter), it only "knows" the current one

Comment: Oh! now I get it!! Thank you very much Alon Eitan!!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
for (x, y, z)
```

- x happens before the loop is entered for the first time
- y is tested at the start of each loop
- z happens at the end of each loop

So:

1. You loop a number of times
2. At the end of the loop i is incremented to 10
3. At the start of the loop i is confirmed to be less than or equal to 10
4. At the end of the loop i is incremented to 11
5. At the start of the loop i is no longer less than or equal to 10
6. The Final output line is executed and i is still 11

Comment: Thank you guys for the specific explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more about the for loop statement. First of all the variable i gets intialized with 1. Then the condition `i <= 10` is checked. Next the inner loop is executed. Because you call `continue`, it goes back to the third part of the for-loop and increments i (`i++`). After that the condition is checked again and so on.

At the final check is i no longer `<= 10` (when it is 11). That is the value that will be displayed in your last statement.

`document.write` in the for loop is never reached.

Comment: Thank you guys for the specific explanation!! And yes I'm newbie in javascript! :D